# Vuejs data not showing properly on mounted

Tags: firebase, vue.js, chart.js

Im new in Vuejs. I started a project with Vue, Firebase and using Chart Js inside of it. Here is the details of problem.

If I give any value of **sales_today** in **data()** it shows properly on mounted where I use it by **this.sales_today** also works perfectly in template **{{sales_today}}**.

But into the Created I'm trying to change this.**sales_today** value by an output of firebase query. then the output shows perfectly into template **{{sales_today}}**  but not working inside the mounted here

```
 **data: [this.sales_today,30,60,10]**
```

**Template**

```
<template>
   {{sales_today}}
</template>
```

**Data**

```
data(){
  return{
        sales_today:''            
    }
},
```

**Mounted**

```
mounted() {
    data: {
         datasets: [{                     
               data: [this.sales_today,30,60,10],                        
         }]
    }    
}
```

**Created**

```
created(){
     let ref = db.collection('sales').where("sales_date", "==", moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY'))
       .get()
       .then(snapshot => {
        var total = 0;
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
           total += Number(doc.data().price)
        })
        this.sales_today = total
     })
}
```

Here is the complete code
https://github.com/Shakilzaman87/pukucrm/blob/master/src/components/dashboard/Dashboard.vue

Comment: Since on created you make  a request which is asyncron , the response comes too late , so this.sales_today on mounted have the old value

Comment: can you tell me how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: the easiest and fastest way to do this is to move the code from created on mounted and after you set this.sales_today = total , to put the code that was before on mounted, so you will initialize chart after the response is received

Comment: I don't understand your `mounted` method, why do you have `data` in there like that?

Comment: a better and more correct way is to use async and await , i think you can do that with firebase and basically created will move after the response is received , so you will have this.sales_today on mounted

Comment: @Decade Moon check the github link, it isn't vuejs data there, it is chartjs data

Comment: Munteanu Patrisor:   I replace the firebase code from created to mounted but still not working .. same result like previous

Comment: it is on github ?

Comment: no I test in my local server

Answer (score 0):

This should be on mounted(). I don't have the editor on comments and i will answer here.

```
let ref = db.collection('sales').where("sales_date", "==", moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY'))
   .get()
   .then(snapshot => {
    var total = 0;
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
       total += Number(doc.data().price)
    })
    this.sales_today = total;

        var chart = this.$refs.chart;
        var ctx = chart.getContext("2d");
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels:this.labels,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Sales of June',
                    data: [this.sales_today,30,60,10],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        '#ffffff'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        '#1976d2'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 3
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            },
        });


 })
```

P.S. check the console for errors